# Using system call in c

Tags: c

Please tell me how to open two files simultaneouly using system();

I want to open two file 
and I am doing it like

```
system("C:\temp\file1.doc");
system("C:\temp\file2.doc");
```

But here till the file 1 is open file 2 is not opening as the control is not able to reach the second system call , Is there a way to do open them simultaneously.

Thanks
Shashank

Comment: If you know you want to use, say, MS Word, then you could do it with one command: `system("C:\Program Files\<path_to_word> C:\temp\file1.doc C:\temp\file2.doc");`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two ways.

1. Run two threads. Call `system()` from each thread.
2. Create a child process using `fork()` and run `system()` from both parent and child processes.